# Can I control Exception in JVM options?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I can not directly modify the Java code by any means.
However, I have a steady exception, and I want to apply a `try` - `catch` to it.
Is this possible with the jvm option?

Comment: what would your `catch` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: *No. It isn't possible.*

If you want to catch an exception you need to modify the code to do it.

If that option is not available, contact the people who supplied / sold you the product and discuss possible workarounds with them:

- You may be using the product incorrectly.
- They may acknowledge that it is a bug, and provide you with a fix.

If that doesn't work, and you are truly desperate, it might be possible to reverse engineer the code and modify it to handle the exception.  However, this approach has various risks.  But bear in mind that you *are* modifying the code.

---

I can think of a few reasons why such an option does not exist / has not been implemented.

- Such a modification (injection of a `catch` for an unwanted exception) changes the behavior the application.  That is unsafe / dangerous, and making it less dangerous is likely to be difficult.
- The technically correct solution is most likely change the program, or the way that you are using it.
- There would be potential business risks to Oracle if they implemented such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

While Stephen C's answer is the first path you should go down, you *can always modify* the code (unless you are legally prevented from doing so)

You can

- decompile the class, edit it and compile it again.
- use Instrumentation to modify the class on the fly.

Neither of these solutions are simple, and a much better approach is to solve the cause of the Exception in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me from your question of your exact problem so my suggestion might not be applicable for you scenario, but could you set an [uncaught exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-)?

From the Javadocs:

> Set the default handler invoked when a thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception, and no other handler has been defined for that thread.